# Cargar un css dentro de un if...else en un script

Tags: javascript, css, estilos

quiero cargar css alternativos dependiendo de si la url contiene la cadena "productos"

tengo este codigo como prueba , que funciona bien.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 cadenaurl=location.href;
   if (/productos/.test(cadenaurl))
     alert("carga css A ");
   else
     alert("carga css B ");

</script>
```

Hasta aqui bien, la condicional funciona y muestra el mensaje correcto.
Ahora quiero aplicar la sentencia para que cargue el css selecionado. Pero no consigo que lo haga
No carga ninguna de la opciones. He comprobado la sentencia fuera del script y carga el css correctamente.
Que estoy hacendo mal ?.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   cadenaurl=location.href;
     if (/productos/.test(cadenaurl))
       <link href="https://../data/estilos/css/estilo1.css"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css">
     else
       <link href="https://../data/estilos/css/estilo2.css"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css">
     
 </script>
```

Comment: Creo que eso lo solucionarlas mejor desde el backend usando templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta agregar un `document.write` dentro del if y else. Quedaria algo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   cadenaurl=location.href;
     if (/productos/.test(cadenaurl))
       document.write('<link href="https://../data/estilos/css/estilo1.css"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css">');
     else
       document.write('<link href="https://../data/estilos/css/estilo2.css"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css">');
     
 </script>
```

Espero te sirva, si te funciona hazlo saber.